# Is there a way to automate migration form Assetic to gulp?

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, gulp, twig, assetic

I'm working on a project with Symfony2 and It happens to be using Assetic to manage css and js.

I'm used to gulp/grant tasks but not with Symfony, I tried to find a systematic (or automatic) way to extract the asset files i use in my templates, group them and replace assetic blocks in twig with the appropriate alternative.

I'm sure a tool like this is going to be a life saver and help migrating old project from Assetic to a modern task runner since it is too limited.

Any suggestion on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I migrated from Assetic to gulp, but it's not an automated process.

In my case, I had to change all the front-end architecture, using the **7--1** pattern. Also I created a gulpfile in the root of the Symfony project. You can create that in some bundle, in the `Resources` folder.

Assuming that you do not want to change your files location, I recommend you to follow this steps:

- Create a `package.json`running **npm init**
- Install gulp, browserify and all of your required packages.
- Move all of your css/scss files to the `app/Resources` folder. It's a best practice to have your assets there. For example you can create an `app/Resources/styles` folder for your styles and `app/Resources/scripts` for your scripts.
- Create a gulpfile.js in the root, or in the Resources folder of some bundle.
- Add the tasks to compile scss and js files in one.

  ```
  gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/Resources/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe($.sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css/'))
  });

  gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('app/Resources/scripts/main.js')
    .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'))
   });
  ```

The `browserify` task compiles all of your javascript modules written in ES6 with browserity, of course.

Finally, you can add tasks for watching, but it's not related with the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mario. Is placing assets in app/Resources still a best practice even in a project whith multiple namespaces and bundles?

Comment: I recognize that I am not a backend developer, but my teammates told me about this best practice. Also you can put your templates in this folder. http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html

Comment: the main issue i'm trying to solve, is a way to extract current assets paths used in templates and re include the right paths done by the task runner. This can be a gulp task too. But i don't see how to start

Comment: I only told my experience migrating from assetic to gulp. It's not possible with gulp to get this migration automatically.